# Disable mouse scroll when overflow-x: hidden [CSS,HTML]

Tags: javascript, html, css

PROBLEM:
The contents of my div are positioned 'absolute' and the width of the contents are larger than the div. 
As required the "extra" contents are clipped using "overflow-x: hidden".

Although, if I try to horizontal scroll using the mouse-scroller, the content get visible.

How do I not let this happen ? I am fine with using a JS or/and a CSS solution

e.g code

```
<body width='1000px'>
  <div style='background-color: blue; width: 1200px'>contents</div>
</body>
```

Thanks !

Comment: what happens if you do `overflow: hidden;` instead of `overflow-x: hidden;`?

Comment: wow ! Thats fixes it. But no ! :(
As I required overflow-y: auto !

Damn !

Comment: What about `overflow:hidden; overflow-y:auto;` ? You can use both.

Comment: Consider posting more information in general about *why* it did not work. The more information you give back, the clearer the problem becomes to us.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem, if you place it within a wrapper then it prevents trackpad scrolling.

```
#wrapper { 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This is the easiest and cleanest solution.

Comment: This was a big help thanks @sgengler. You can actually use this directly on `body` if you set `overflow-x: hidden;` and `position: relative;` on it

Answer (score 1):

I think the default behavior for the document body is to allow scrolling of content that is too big for it. This seems like it might not be too easy to work around.

Instead of specifying a width on your BODY, you could try using one more DIV and putting the width on that instead.

```
<div style="width:1000px;">
  <div style="width:1200px;"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a reason you have to put width on the BODY tag?

Comment: I have actually not put a width to the body tag. (mentioned that only to make the sizes clear). 
Trying the wrapper div now.

Answer (score -2):

You must use

`$("element").on('mousedown', function(e) {}`

Just change `live` to `on`