# overflow-x to avoid any horizontal scrolling in browser

Tags: jquery, html, css, scroll, overflow

**PROBLEM RESOLVED**
SO I have this issue that I cannot for the life figure out:

I made a dropdown to be shown on the whole page no matter what size and this seems to work:

http://jsfiddle.net/Riskbreaker/y9wZz/

The problem is if you force your mouse to the right it scrolls unwanted scrolling and obviously this is the root of all evil:

```
.dd {
    margin: 0 -1000em;
    padding: 0 1000em;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

I tried this:

```
body {overflow-x: hidden;}
```

*(Note I tried HTML overflow-x too)*.....**of course it removes the scrollbar(horizontal)** but thats not the issue....FF listens and does not scroll at all if you tried to force it BUT, the rest...Chrome/IE/Safari do scroll....Is there a solution to make this work?

This person had something similar but no answer here:
[overflow-x:hidden still can scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8635799/overflow-xhidden-still-can-scroll)

Lastly I tried this:

```
$(element).scroll(function () {
    this.scrollLeft = 0;
});
```

but didnt do anything.

**SOLUTION**
I just needed to add this on html:
`html {overflow: hidden; overflow-y: auto;}`...thanks all

Comment: @Blazemonger - where do you get that idea? Firefox has understood `overflow-x`/`overflow-y` for years...

Comment: @BenD Indeed you're right. Apparently I'm thinking of `background-position`.

Comment: I'm looking at your jsfiddle on Firefox, Chrome, and IE, and I don't see any scroll bars anywhere. Am I just misunderstanding? could you provide a screenshot?

Comment: AS i said no scrollbars show...but you can still scroll to right if you force it...thats what I want to prevent (thinking iPad)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUTION** I just needed to add this on html: html {overflow: hidden; overflow-y: auto;}...thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Change these settings...these extend way to the right of your sections/divs and body.

margin: 0 -1000em;
padding: 0 1000em;

I changed it to -100px and 100px respectively and it still scrolled to the right slightly, but stopped.

Comment: I know 100px is too small for this particular set up, but it illustrates what is causing the problem.

Comment: thanks but as I mentioned in my post....that IS what is causing this I need a way to make it work using this...Is there another way to get your dropdown menu 100% of full page?

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through all the other solutions but unfortunately none of them worked for me.

I have a easiest solution and that is a `css` rule

```
.nicescroll-rails-hr{display:none!important}
```

Hope it will help you too.