# IE + overflow: hidden

Tags: css, internet-explorer, overflow, internet-explorer-10, internet-explorer-11

I don't know is that an issue or bug, but when I use `overflow: hidden`, selecting the text and moving the cursor to the page bottom in IE, the page is scrolling (I tried IE9-IE11)! When I use Firefox/Opera/Chrome/Safari the page isn't scrolling... I have to use `overflow: hidden`, but it has an odd behavior in IE.

So, my question is: how can I avoid page scrolling in IE?

Comment: Without a code sample it's hard to tell what's happening.

Comment: It's not a bug - `overflow: hidden` does not prevent scrolling, it just hides the scrolling UI.

Comment: @easwee, here is the code I'm using - http://jsfiddle.net/LwaDm/

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `-ms-scroll-limit: 0 0 0 0;` to prevent any scrolling whatsoever in IE 10+. 
For older browsers you can write a workaround using JavaScript.

Example of CSS and JavaScript:

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-scroll-limit: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

```js
window.onscroll = function (event) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

```js
window.onscroll = function (event) {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0);
}
```

```css
body {
  overflow: hidden;
  -ms-scroll-limit: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
    We choose to go to the moon in this decade and do the other things, not because they are easy, but because they are hard, because that goal will serve to organize and measure the best of our energies and skills, because that challenge is one that we are willing to accept, one we are unwilling to postpone, and one which we intend to win.

    We choose to go to the moon in this decade and do the other things, not because they are easy, but because they are hard, because that goal will serve to organize and measure the best of our energies and skills, because that challenge is one that we are willing to accept, one we are unwilling to postpone, and one which we intend to win.

    Never in all their history have men been able truly to conceive of the world as one: a single sphere, a globe, having the qualities of a globe, a round earth in which all the directions eventually meet, in which there is no center because every point, or none, is center — an equal earth which all men occupy as equals. The airman's earth, if free men make it, will be truly round: a globe in practice, not in theory.

    What was most significant about the lunar voyage was not that man set foot on the Moon but that they set eye on the earth.

    If you could see the earth illuminated when you were in a place as dark as night, it would look to you more splendid than the moon.

    When I orbited the Earth in a spaceship, I saw for the first time how beautiful our planet is. Mankind, let us preserve and increase this beauty, and not destroy it!

    Buy why, some say, the moon? Why choose this as our goal? And they may as well ask why climb the highest mountain?

    Across the sea of space, the stars are other suns.

    Many say exploration is part of our destiny, but it’s actually our duty to future generations and their quest to ensure the survival of the human species.

    As we got further and further away, it [the Earth] diminished in size. Finally it shrank to the size of a marble, the most beautiful you can imagine. That beautiful, warm, living object looked so fragile, so delicate, that if you touched it with a finger it would crumble and fall apart. Seeing this has to change a man.

    If you could see the earth illuminated when you were in a place as dark as night, it would look to you more splendid than the moon.

    We have an infinite amount to learn both from nature and from each other

    To go places and do things that have never been done before – that’s what living is all about.

    Spaceflights cannot be stopped. This is not the work of any one man or even a group of men. It is a historical process which mankind is carrying out in accordance with the natural laws of human development.

    Space, the final frontier. These are the voyages of the Starship Enterprise. Its five-year mission: to explore strange new worlds, to seek out new life and new civilizations, to boldly go where no man has gone before.

    To be the first to enter the cosmos, to engage, single-handed, in an unprecedented duel with nature—could one dream of anything more?

    We have an infinite amount to learn both from nature and from each other

    Many say exploration is part of our destiny, but it’s actually our duty to future generations and their quest to ensure the survival of the human species.

    NASA is not about the ‘Adventure of Human Space Exploration’…We won’t be doing it just to get out there in space – we’ll be doing it because the things we learn out there will be making life better for a lot of people who won’t be able to go.

    Never in all their history have men been able truly to conceive of the world as one: a single sphere, a globe, having the qualities of a globe, a round earth in which all the directions eventually meet, in which there is no center because every point, or none, is center — an equal earth which all men occupy as equals. The airman's earth, if free men make it, will be truly round: a globe in practice, not in theory.

    Where ignorance lurks, so too do the frontiers of discovery and imagination.

    Astronomy compels the soul to look upward, and leads us from this world to another.

    We have an infinite amount to learn both from nature and from each other

    Curious that we spend more time congratulating people who have succeeded than encouraging people who have not.

    Where ignorance lurks, so too do the frontiers of discovery and imagination.

    Curious that we spend more time congratulating people who have succeeded than encouraging people who have not.

    Where ignorance lurks, so too do the frontiers of discovery and imagination.

    A Chinese tale tells of some men sent to harm a young girl who, upon seeing her beauty, become her protectors rather than her violators. That's how I felt seeing the Earth for the first time. I could not help but love and cherish her.

    What was most significant about the lunar voyage was not that man set foot on the Moon but that they set eye on the earth.

    That's one small step for [a] man, one giant leap for mankind.
```

(`overflow: hidden` is apparently inconsistent across browsers, but I do not know which browser does it right.)

Comment: It's good, but MSDN says, that it's supported by IE10 and higher and only on Windows 8/Windows 8.1...

Comment: I can confirm that it works in IE 11 on Windows 7. Unfortunately I don't know of a solution for IE 9 and older.

Comment: IE8 and earlier is not a problem, but IE9... is there a solution on JavaScript?

Comment: Sure, it's possible to fix this with JavaScript. I updated the answer with a link.

Comment: I think, that would be the last answer: in your JavaScript code you are using `ScroolTo` method, but is there a way to cancel that event, not just using `ScroolTo`?

Comment: Try using event.preventDefault(), but I don't think it will work.

Comment: Note: in my experience, `overflow: hidden` does work for IE11. In my case, it was being overriden by something else.

Comment: it's fantastic, I spent 2 days with my problem and just this `-ms-scroll-limit: 0 0 0 0` solved my problem.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the -ms-overflow-style property?

```
-ms-overflow-style: none;
```

More information available here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh771902(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: MSDN: "Unlike overflow: hidden, elements with -ms-overflow-style: none can still be scrolled via touch panning, keyboard, or mouse wheel.", but I have to disable scroll at all. And when I select the text and move the mouse to the page bottom - it scrolls

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution for it but not sure that this is the right way or not but you can try it.

http://jsfiddle.net/b5DYf/1/

```
html{
  position:fixed;
}
```

Comment: That is for sure not the right way, as it makes content unreachable as soon as it extends the viewport!

Comment: @Netsurfer That's what OP wants to do

Comment: @Mr.Alien I am quite sure thta he wants to do this for one or more elements on the page. But certainly not shrinking the whole page to the viewport and making all extending content unreachable!

Comment: @Netsurfer Yea, that's a point, though I feel he wants for the page ***how can I avoid page scrolling in IE?***

Comment: @Mr.Alien Yeah, but don't miss the part:"... selecting the text and moving the cursor to the page ..."! So imho this answer isn't helpful and I wanted to give the author the chance to edit it, instead of just downvoting. Personally I think "It's a feature, not a bug!". Because why should content be unreachable!? If this is desired, why is it there?

Comment: @Netsurfer Yea it is intentional, if the dimensions are fixed, I can solve this issue using `clip` property :)

Comment: is there another way to avoid scrolling? And why it scrolls only in IE?