# IE11/10 HTML5 main tag and overflow:hidden bug

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

Most basic of problems, but I've spent hours searching and can't find the answer.

```
<main style="height:0px;overflow:hidden;">
    <section>
       This should not be displayed
    </section>
</main>
```

This code returns blank in Safari, Chrome, and Firefox as expected.  But IE10/11 shows "This should not be displayed."

https://jsfiddle.net/6a204ad9/8/

Obviously the overflow is not working.

I've tried setting height and width to both main and section.  I've tried position:relative (IE6 bug).

It's something so basic... I know this is stupid and probably answered 10000 times, but I'm at my wits end.  The "duh" answer is...?

Thanks!

Comment: So you want to hide the content in all browers? Or just want to find out why `overflow: hidden` doesn't work as expected in IE?

Comment: @aphextwix I'd prefer to know why overflow:hidden doesn't work so I can fix that directly instead of using a different method.  But if a different method will work on all browsers (and preserve the 0px height of the parent), I'm all ears.

Comment: I suggested a name change for this question, which is primarily about the HTML5 main tag. There's another issue with overflow: hidden and IE at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21975342/ie-overflow-hidden

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is because the `<main>` HTML5 tag is not supported in IE10/11.

If you change your HTML to :

```
<div style="height:0px;overflow:hidden;">
    <div>
       This should not be displayed
    </div>
</div>
```

You should no longer see the content displayed.

Or you could add `display: block` to your `<main>` tag.

See link :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main

Comment: Thank you!  I didn't occur to me that a "modern" browser like IE 11 didn't support main and section HTML5 tags.

Comment: @D.Walsh - It does support `<section>` but not `<main>` so there won't be any default styling applied by the browser like there would be with a `<div>`

Answer (score 1):

For an arbitrarily named element, you'll need to use the `display` style attribute to tell Internet Explorer how you want the element to behave.

For example, if you want your `<main>` element to behave like a `<div>`, give it a style attribute of `display:block;`

```html
<main style="height:0px;overflow:hidden;display:block;">
    <section>
       This should not be displayed
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: That was it.  Works fine.  I never dreamed that IE11 didn't support fairly old HTML5 tags.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome! Yeah, looks like Edge recognizes `<main>` but IE11 does not.

Comment: @D.Walsh Don't forget to mark mine or aphextwix's response as the answer to your question so people know that it's been resolved.