# Controlling the scroll of div A while scrolling div B with mousewheel and vice versa

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I have 2 div that act like a list or a table i am trying to make div A's scrolling scroll div B and vice versa. with the mousewheel.

The issue with that is since i bind "scroll" on both, when i set scrollTop = something from div B for div A it will also trigger the "scroll" of div A.

What i came up with is: on `mouseover` - bind "scroll" for current element, then on `mouseout` unbind it and in the bind function i change the scrollTop example:

```
 $('#parent1, #parent2').off('mouseover').on( 'mouseover', function () {
     var that = this;
     refresh(that);
     $(this).off( 'scroll').on( 'scroll', function () {
         refresh(that);   
     });
 } ).off('mouseout').on( 'mouseout', function () {
     $(this).off( 'scroll');
     refresh(this);
 });

function refresh(that){
    if(that == $('#parent1')[0]){
        $('#parent2').scrollTop($(that).scrollTop()); 
    }else{
        $('#parent1').scrollTop($(that).scrollTop());
    }
}
```

See it in action in: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q8xL3/7/)

however when scrolling and moving from 1 div to another fast enough it causes trouble and wont work correctly.

Anyone with an idea ?

Ah ignore the following code in the fiddle:

```
var i= 0;
$('#parent1 div').each(function(index, div){
    $(div).append(" " + i);
    i++;
});

var i= 0;
$('#parent2 div').each(function(index, div){
    $(div).append(" " + i);
    i++;
});
```

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: The expression is *vice versa*.

Comment: instead of saying "ignore this" you could edit this out of your fiddle and update your question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an event listener that when you scroll A it updates the scroll position of B. But for that you need a flag so that when you set the scroll B position it don't trigger the scroll B event.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qBvM/

```
var ignoreEvent = false;

$('#parent1').scroll( function() {
    var ignore = ignoreEvent;
    ignoreEvent = false
    if (!ignore) {
        ignoreEvent = true;
        $('#parent2').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());
    }} );

$('#parent2').scroll( function() {
    var ignore = ignoreEvent;
    ignoreEvent = false;
    if (!ignore) {
        ignoreEvent = true;
        $('#parent1').scrollTop($(this).scrollTop());  
    }} );
```

(With help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386696/make-scrollleft-scrolltop-changes-not-trigger-scroll-event))