# Can I dynamically change the scroll speed of a website to speed up as the user scrolls further down?

Tags: html, jquery, css, web

I'm quite new to HTML and hoping to make a prototype of a website where as you scroll further down, the scroll speed increases. Does anyone have any idea how to do this?

Comment: Scroll speed/distance is an OS setting, which is respected by most modern browsers (on Windows search for "Choose how many lines to scroll each time"). If you want to customize the scrolling behavior, you have to implement it yourself in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

You could watch the onscroll event and, depending of the scrollTop and the scroll direction, apply another scrollTop value.

Beware changing scrollTop would trigger the onscroll event again, creating an infinite loop, so you would have to set up a flag like explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386696/make-scrollleft-scrolltop-changes-not-trigger-scroll-event-listener).