# Scrolling multiple divs in js

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, event-handling

I have more than two divs which i would like to scroll, it does not matter which one i scroll, they all should move for same amount at the same time. The problem i have is that el.scrollLeft fires the listener again. I also tried to disable function on wheel and enable it on end of scrolling, but the problem is that on one wheel event multiple scroll events happen (as i researched you cant disable this smooth scrolling on chrome?) This is my current code which does not work.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.rowDataDiv').forEach(el =>
    el.addEventListener('scroll', e =>
        document.querySelectorAll('.rowDataDiv').forEach(el =>
            el.scrollLeft = e.target.scrollLeft
        );
    );
);
```

EDIT:
I want to avoid the loop caused by scrollLeft if I wasnt clear enough

Comment: What's wrong apart from missing braces that is?

Comment: @Vinay as I said the el.scrollLeft fires the same listener and it does not stop firing which slows the website. also you do not need braces for one line of code.

Comment: @chrslg what about the problem

Comment: I don't think you can avoid explicitly testing which div fired the scroll event, and then changing all others

Comment: @chrslg are there any workarounds?

Comment: As @Vinay said, it already works correctly tho. So you could let it as it. Unless on some specific navigator that trigger an event loop. But on mine it doesn't. Just a useless event, but no loop

Comment: @chrslg it does fire a loop. if you pay attention at the start and end of scrolling div you will see that it slows down drastically, you need to scroll a lot more to cover smaller distance than usual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, new answer, now that I understand better the question.

And quite a convoluted one.

Note that it is almost a duplicate question:
[Make "scrollLeft" / "scrollTop" changes not trigger scroll event listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386696/make-scrollleft-scrolltop-changes-not-trigger-scroll-event-listener)

And I took my inspiration from the best answer there.
The difference, and it is bigger than it seems at first glance, is that in that question there are only 2 divs, plus, the initial event is fired explicitly from code. So they know when to start ignoring future events. And they know when they can stop ignoring them.

But the base problem is the same: events are fired afterward. And the scroll event most often doesn't come alone.
So you have a burst of scroll events coming from (say) first div. And then some other scroll events coming from the update of scrollLeft. And you can't assume anything about the order in which those events will occur.

Note that the browser would not fire a scroll event if setting scrollLeft doesn't change scrollLeft value.
Which is both

- the reason why your code is not so bad as is (it works, and it doesn't get caught in an infinite loop. Just, looking closely, sometimes, when subsequent event from previous updating of scrollLeft fires **after** another mouse event, the scrolling movement can't temporarily go backward (which I can't really see with my naked eye. But is visible when logging positions).
- another reason why the answer is not that simple (one dealt in the question I quoted). General idea is to ignore events while updating scrollLeft on other div. But to know when to stop ignoring event, you have to do this in the event handler. Because doing so after updating all scrollLeft is too soon: event from those update haven't been fired yet. But you have to take into account that event handler is not always called after a scrollLeft update. Precisely because of the reason why your version does not work so bad: event handler is called only if a real change has been made.

So, all together, my solution

```js
// orgTarget is the div which fire the first (the real, coming from user interaction) event
// Initialy there is none
let orgTarget=false;

// Same callback for all div
function onScroll(e){
    // If we don't have a orgTarget, that means we weren't in the middle of updating scrollLeft. THe event come from the user interaction.
    // So  e.target is our originator div. 
    if(orgTarget===false) orgTarget=e.target;
    // pos is the scroll position we are trying to propagate
    // (Note that pos come from orgTarget, not from e.target)
    let pos=orgTarget.scrollLeft;
    // If current callback is called because of orgTarget, that is because of user interaction, then update all scrollLeft
    if(orgTarget==e.target){
        for(let d of divList){
            if(d.scrollLeft!=pos){
                d.scrollLeft=pos; // This could have been outside the if: it would have no consequence (no future event) if it were useless anyway. But just to be sure, update only when needed
                // important line is this one: when we change scrollLeft of d, we can expect a scroll event from d. Use an attribute of d to remind that we are expecting an event here
                d.scrollEventToCome=true;
            }
        }
    }
    // We got an event for e.target (that is why we are running this callback)
    // So, if we were expecting one, we can stop expecting it: we got it
    e.target.scrollEventToCome=false;
    // Just check if there is still an event to come in any div
    let stillWaiting=false;
    for(let d of divList){
        if(d.scrollEventToCome) stillWaiting=true;
    }
    // if no event are expected from any div, then we can reset orgTarget
    // which means that the next event will be considered a "real" event
    if(!stillWaiting) orgTarget=false;
}

for(let d of divList){
    d.addEventListener('scroll', onScroll);
}
```

So, the idea is quite similar to the one in the post I referenced:

- Before updating scrollLeft, note in some way that coming events should not trigger further modification of scrollLeft
- To know when to stop ignoring future even, we do it in the event listener (before, it would be too soon), when we got all the "fake" event we were expecting.

In the referenced message, this was done just by a global `ignoreEvent` variable. Meaning "we expect ONE fake event". Which was reset in the event handler, when we got the expected fake event (I call "fake event" the one coming from an explicit update of scrollLeft, and "real event" the one coming from user interaction). Being careful of a possible exception: if scrollLeft is not really updated, then we should let `ignoreEvent` to false immediatly, and not wait for the listener of a coming fake event, since none is to come.

Here we have to take note of several fake events: each time a real event occurs, we update plenty of scrollLeft. Which will generate plenty of fake event. But there also, taking into account that fake event are to be expected only if scrollLeft is really updated.

We also have to take into account that, while we are in the middle of receiving a burst of fake event because of a first real event, another event can occur, from the same div.

Hence my solution:

- keep tracks of which div triggered the real event (orgTarget)
- process events from that div (the first real one, but also some other real events from that div that may occur in the middle of the process)
- update scrollLeft on all other divs. And keep track of which future fake event we are expecting
- when we receive a fake event (that is an event that is not coming from the orgTarget div), note that we are not expecting it anymore
- when we are not expecting any fake event, we can't stop the ignoring process, and expect a new series of real event. Which is done by resetting `orgTarget` to false.

I tested it. It works as expected. I never experienced any "backward" scrolling. It does only the strictly needed scrollLeft update (each time scrollLeft of one div is changed by a user action, it update once, and only once, scrollLeft of all other divs. It does so only if needed, just to not depend on that "event is not fired if scrollLeft is not really updated" behavior).

Comment: This is almost same as my code you just skip the element you originally scrolled. This is not the solution I am looking for because every other element that you reposition with scrollLeft also fires scroll event and you are again in a loop. It works almost as same as mine but it is not optimal solution.

Comment: Yes indeed. I was just trying to avoid triggering and event on myself ("myself" being the div that started the scroll), and forgot about "fire back" from others.

Comment: This invalidate my answer (I will delete it, unless I come up with another solution).

Comment: Although I insist that there is no loop of events. I ``console.log``ed this in an example. And it doesn't loop, at least not forever and not even a lot. A few event are fired. I haven't thouroughly checked whether they are from scroll fired at each other or not (moving a scroll bar with the mouse fire more than one scroll event anyway). But, it works as is. At least with firefox and chrome.

Comment: yes I also saw that it is not infinite loop, probably browser blocks it or something. I have a problem at the start and end of div where the scrolling is slower for some reason

Comment: thank you for your answer, i will mark it as solution. I fixed my code to move all containers to a parent container and then scroll the parent which is not actually solving the current project. Maybe what are we trying to do is generally wrong aproach but anyway thank you for helping.